# what is the point of parentheses around assignment expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

I read the following code [here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

```
({ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 });
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20
```

What is the difference between that and the following:

```
{ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 };
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20
```

Considering that they have the same outcome.

P.S. The point is the parentheses around the assignment expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example shouldn't work. You should see an error.

```
let a, b;
{ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 };

// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
```

The reason is that the curly brackets `{ a, b }` are considered a block not an object literal.

```
// This is a block
{
    console.log('Hello world');
}
```

When surounded by parentheses it's considered an object literal

```
({ hello: world })
```

> Note: The parentheses ( ... ) around the assignment statement are
> required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a
> declaration.
>
> {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2} is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the {a, b}
> on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, ({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}) is valid, as is const {a, b} = {a: 1,
> b: 2}
>
> Your ( ... ) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may
> be used to execute a function on the previous line.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assignment_without_declaration